# Explanation of R^2 with partition of variance

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, r-squared

In the context of multiple linear regression, I'm looking for an explanation of $R^2$ with as few concepts as possible. I came up with the following:

**Explanation**

Data is modeled as $y = \hat{y} + \varepsilon$, where $\hat{y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2$ is the predicted value and $\varepsilon$ the residual. The regression ensures that $\hat{y}$ and $\varepsilon$ are uncorrelated, so we have $V(y) = V(\hat{y}) + V(\varepsilon)$. The variance observed in the data can thus be partitioned in variance explained by the model: $V(\hat{y})$ and variance that remains unexplained: $V(\varepsilon)$. We are interested in the ratio between explained and total variance: $\frac{V(\hat{y})}{V(y)} = 1-\frac{V(\varepsilon)}{V(y)}$.

Using sample variances as estimates, we define $R^2 = 1-\dfrac{s^2_\varepsilon}{s^2_y} = 1-\dfrac{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i(\varepsilon_i-\bar{\varepsilon})^2}{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i(y-\bar{y})^2}$.

If the model includes a constant term $\beta_0\neq 0$ then $\bar{\varepsilon}=0$ and we have: $R^2 = 1 - \dfrac{\sum_i\varepsilon_i^2}{\sum_i(y_i-\bar{y})^2} = 1 - \frac{RSS}{TSS}$.

**Questions**

Is the general idea correct? Are there mistakes, confusions or missing assumptions?

Comment: Regression assumes that noise is uncorrelated, rather than ensuring it, but this may be just a matter of wording.

Comment: $R^2$ is the square of the correlation between observed and predicted outcomes. The appeal of that characterisation depends on whether correlation is regarded as itself in need of explanation. But that is what you are doing here by taking "uncorrelated" as understood. All stances are arguable, but I don't think any sample and population distinction is essential here. A side-effect of this story is that it makes the notation more obvious.

Comment: @Tim this seems to contradict Gelman and Hill's *Data analysis using regression and multilevel/hierarchical models* where it says "As a byproduct of the least squares estimation of $\beta$, the residuals $r_i$ will be uncorrelated with all the predictors in the model. If the model includes a constant term, then the residuals must be uncorrelated with a constant, which means they must have mean 0. This is a byproduct of how the model is estimated; it is *not* a regression assumption". Are we talking of different things?

Comment: @NickCox I should have titled the question "Explanation of $R^2$ with partition of variance" since that's what I'm really trying to do.

Regarding the distinction between sample and population variance, I thought I needed population variance to write an equality $V(y) = V(\hat{y}) + V(\varepsilon)$ but I guess that's where I was confused: the regression actually gives $s^2_y = s^2_{\hat y} + s^2_{\varepsilon}$.

Can you elaborate on what makes the notation more obvious?

Comment: I had nothing in mind beyond $R^2$ being $R$, squared where $R$ denotes correlation.

Comment: If you truly want "as few concepts as possible," it suffices to remark that this variance decomposition is a statement of the [Pythagorean Theorem:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=pythagorean%20theorem) that doesn't require *any* statistical concepts (or calculation).